# SciKit-learn (python)--Create my dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have installed scikit-learn and I don’t know how to use it. I have some data that looks like this :

```
{"Tiempo": 2.1,  "Brazos": "der", "Puntuacion ": 112, "Nombre": "Alguien1"},
{"Tiempo": 4.1, "Brazos": "izq", "Puntuacion ": 11, "Nombre": "Alguien2"},
{"Tiempo": 3.211,  "Brazos": "ambos","Puntuacion ": 1442, "Nombre": "Alguien3"}
```

And I would like to use some classifiers (like SVM) on them. For what I have seen in the examples, I need to create a dataset. In the examples they always use some predetermined datasets as “iris”. In my case, I suppose that I would need to create my own using my data. In order to do it, I searched and I found that I should use the next functions to obtain the “features” of my dataset:

```
measurements = [
    {'city': 'Dubai', 'temperature': 33.},
    {'city': 'London', 'temperature': 12.},
    {'city': 'San Fransisco', 'temperature': 18.},
]

from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec = DictVectorizer()

vec.fit_transform(measurements).toarray()
array([[  1.,   0.,   0.,  33.],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.,  12.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.,  18.]])

>>> vec.get_feature_names()
['city=Dubai', 'city=London', 'city=San Fransisco', 'temperature']
```

And in my case, after y use that functions with my data I obtain this:
[image]

Once I have this I suppose that I need to obtain my “samples”, however, I don’t know how to do. Could you help me please? And can you tell me if my suppositions are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Use your data as an example.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

# your data
data = [{"Tiempo": 2.1,  "Brazos": "der", "Puntuacion ": 112, "Nombre": "Alguien1"}, {"Tiempo": 4.1, "Brazos": "izq", "Puntuacion ": 11, "Nombre": "Alguien2"}, {"Tiempo": 3.211,  "Brazos": "ambos","Puntuacion ": 1442, "Nombre": "Alguien3"}]

# make dummy for categorical variables
transformer = DictVectorizer()
transformer.fit_transform(data).toarray()

Out[168]: 
array([[  0.0000e+00,   1.0000e+00,   0.0000e+00,   1.0000e+00,   0.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00,   1.1200e+02,   2.1000e+00],
       [  0.0000e+00,   0.0000e+00,   1.0000e+00,   0.0000e+00,   1.0000e+00,
          0.0000e+00,   1.1000e+01,   4.1000e+00],
       [  1.0000e+00,   0.0000e+00,   0.0000e+00,   0.0000e+00,   0.0000e+00,
          1.0000e+00,   1.4420e+03,   3.2110e+00]])

transformer.get_feature_names()

Out[170]: 
['Brazos=ambos',
 'Brazos=der',
 'Brazos=izq',
 'Nombre=Alguien1',
 'Nombre=Alguien2',
 'Nombre=Alguien3',
 'Puntuacion ',
 'Tiempo']
```

So you see, each record in `Out[168]` has 8 columns, the first 3 are categorical dummy for `Brazos` (look at the feature names in `Out[170]`), the next three are dummy for `Nombre`, the last two are continue numeric values `Puntuacion` and `Tiempo` (which doesn't require any conversion and stay as what it was).

```
# to continue to fit the model, transform your raw JSON data to numeric value
X = transformer.fit_transform(data)
# import your estimator
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
estimator = BernoulliNB()
# then start to fit and predict
# NOTE! require your y labels
estimator.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Ok. But with that i only obtain the "fetures" and I would need to obtain the "samples" in order to train the classifier, right? if that is the case, could you tell me how to obtain the samples? Or the samples are the 3 JSONs that I put in the example?

Comment: Samples are numeric-valued 2d-array in `Out[168]`. In `Out[168]`, there are three rows and 8 columns. each row is an observation (that's your three JSON), and each column is a feature.

Comment: Then if `Tiempo` has a value of 2 and `Puntuaciones` 112, that  is reflected in the array `Out[168]`?

Comment: Yes, the 7th column in 1st row is `1.1200e+02` that is 112 in float number, the 8th column in 1st row is `2.1000e+00` is 2.1.

Comment: Ok. About the labels, how does it work? The labels whould be an array of the diferent labels in the JSONs (something like `[Nombre, Tiempo, Puntuacion]`) or it should be an array of numbers `[0,1,2]`?

Comment: scikit-learn algorithms only takes numeric values as inputs, so all JSONs (or other dict-alike containers) have to be converted to either dummy (for categorical variables) or numeric int/float values. This is why we need `DictVectorizer()` to preprocess the data first before we can feed the data into the estimator like `BernoulliNB()` or `SVC()`.

Comment: So, in order to make `BernoulliNB().fit(X,y)` I should load in the `y` the matrix given by `transformer.fit_transform(data).toarray()
`?